# How to implement projects with project admins in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What I'm looking for is an appropriate way to set up a system where users can create projects and therefor become the admin of that project.  The user can then add other admins to the project.  Finally, other non-admin users can join the project.

I want to be able to verify whether a user is an admin of a project to check whether he has edit/update privileges.  Any thoughts?

I figure I'll probably have a users_projects table and a projects_admins table, but I can't figure out how that translates to Rails relationships....

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I will give it a try, but without too much code here in.

I see here 3 models:

- User
- Project
- ProjectAdmin

The first 2 are simple models, with some attributes. The third one is the relation between the two and will be a n:m relation. So it is best to use the has-many-through relation here.

```
class ProjectAdmin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_admins
  has_many :projects, :through => :project_admins
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_admins
  has_many :admins, :through => :project_admins
end
```

Of course you have to create additionally the 3 tables by migrations, and add later a similar relation for project users, named then `ProjectUser` as model. Have at least a look at the [rails guide about relations, section "has-many :through"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association).

To add the creator to a project, this should be a one-one relation between the two, so it should be sufficient to have:

```
class Project
  has_one :creator, :class_name => "User"
end
```

(and of course the `creator_id` in the migration)

Comment: Great!  The only thing this doesn't answer (and I probably should have been more clear about it) is how to keep track of which user created the project.  I was thinking I could add something like belongs_to :creator, class_name => "User", but then what would I put in the User model to compliment that?

Comment: What would I need to put in the User model so that I could find user.created_projects ?  If I did has_many :created_projects, :class_name => "projects", it won't know to pull from the :creator column in the projects table.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.  Just needed to say has_many :created_projects, :class_name => "Project", :foreign_key => "creator_id"

Thanks!